# Assign value from a drop down menu to a variable in a controller which is used in a model in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to dynamically query my database by selecting an option from a drop down menu and assign the value of it using GET method back to a variable in a Controller which is then used in a Model but I am unsure how to go about it.

My code is as follows

View - holds the drop down menu

```
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Latest Hurling  Fixtures<b class="caret"></b></a>

   <ul class="dropdown-menu">

     <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('user/get_fixtures?fixture_type=Hurling&fixture_level=Roinn 1A') ?>">Roinn 1A</a></li>

     <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo site_url('user/get_fixtures?fixture_type=Hurling&fixture_level=Roinn 1B') ?>">Roinn 1B</a></li>

     <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('user/get_fixtures?fixture_type=Hurling&fixture_level=Roinn 2A') ?>">Roinn 2A</a></li>

     <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('user/get_fixtures?fixture_type=Hurling&fixture_level=Roinn 2B') ?>">Roinn 2B</a></li>
    </ul> 
  </li>
```

I am trying to assign the values "Hurling" and "Roinn 1A" etc ( depending on which menu item is chosen) back to variables in the "get_fixtures" function in my Controller which is called "user"

```
get_fixtures function

public function get_fixtures()
{
 $data['title']= 'Hurling';
 $this->load->model('fixture_model');

 $fixture_round =$_GET['fixture_type'];
 $fixture_level =$_GET['fixture_level'];

 $data['results'] = $this->fixture_model->fixtures();

 $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
 $this->load->view('pages/hurling_view.php', $data);
 $this->load->view('include/footer',$data);
 }
```

I then want to use these variables in my model where I query my database.

MODEL

```
function fixtures() 

{

 //Query the fixture table for every record and row  

 $results = array();

 $this->db->select('tf.*, t1.*, fixture.*, venue.*, t2.team_id as team_id_2, t2.team_name as team_name_2, t2.team_logo as team_logo_2, fixture_text, fixture_type, fixture_comp, fixture_date, fixture_level');
 $this->db->from('team_has_fixture as tf');

 $this->db->join('team as t1', 't1.team_id = tf.team_team_id');
 $this->db->join('team as t2', 't2.team_id = tf.team_team_id2');
 $this->db->join('fixture', 'tf.fixture_fixture_id = fixture.fixture_id');
 $this->db->join('venue', 'fixture_venue_id = venue.venue_id');
 $this->db->where('fixture_type', $fixture_type);
 $this->db->where('fixture_level', $fixture_level);
 $query = $this->db->get();

 //echo $this->db->last_query(); // Used this to see what my latest query contained

  if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
   {
    $results = $query->result();
   }

  //var_dump($query->result()); // used this to see that the results of my query contained

   return $results;         
  }  

 }
```

When I run this I get undefined variable errors.

Comment: You're not passing the $fixture_type & $fixture_level to the model, And you don't have to enable anything in order to use $this->input->get() instead of _GET (use the input class to get added security).

Comment: fixtures() function in your model should be accepting 2 parameters fixtures($fixture_type, $fixture_level) & your controller should be calling the model method supplying the aforementioned parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more digging I have found that the following works for me.

Step 1 - Change URI Protocol in Config file in application folder.

Change it from this

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

to this

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
```

Step 2 - Add the following to the construct method in your Controller

```
    //Allow querystrings for this constructor

    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);
```

Step 3 - I used the following code for my drop down menu in my View - the drop down menu items call a method called "get_fixtures" from my controller which is called "users"

VIEW

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Latest Hurling Fixtures<b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">

   <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('user/get_fixtures?fixture_type=Hurling&fixture_level=Roinn 1A') ?>">Roinn 1A</a></li>
   <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('user/get_fixtures?fixture_type=Hurling&fixture_level=Roinn 1B') ?>">Roinn 1B</a></li>
   <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('user/get_fixtures?fixture_type=Hurling&fixture_level=Roinn 2A') ?>">Roinn 2A</a></li>
   <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('user/get_fixtures?fixture_type=Hurling&fixture_level=Roinn 2B') ?>">Roinn 2B</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('user/hurl_all_ireland') ?>">All Ireland Championship</a></li>  
   </ul> 
</li>
```

get_fixtures function in my controller contains the following

```
public function get_fixtures()
{

 //I used the commented out lines below to test that I was getting a value back from the  GET in my dropdown menu 

 //$fixture_type = $_GET['fixture_type'];
 //$fixture_level = $_GET['fixture_level'];

 //echo $fixture_type;
//echo $fixture_level;*/

 $data['title']= 'Hurling';
 $this->load->model('fixture_model');

 $data['results'] = $this->fixture_model->fixtures();

 $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
 $this->load->view('pages/hurling_view.php', $data);
 $this->load->view('include/footer',$data);

}
```

Step 4 - Finally I set the variables in my Model before querying the database

MODEL

```
function fixtures() 

    {
        //Query the fixture table for every record and row

        // Set the variables to the values selected from the drop down menu
        $fixture_type = $_GET['fixture_type'];
        $fixture_level = $_GET['fixture_level'];  

        $fixture_round = "Round 3";
        //$fixture_level = "Roinn 1A";
        $results = array();

        $this->db->select('tf.*, t1.*, fixture.*, venue.*, t2.team_id as team_id_2, t2.team_name as team_name_2, t2.team_logo as team_logo_2, fixture_text, fixture_type, fixture_comp, fixture_date, fixture_level');
        $this->db->from('team_has_fixture as tf');

        $this->db->join('team as t1', 't1.team_id = tf.team_team_id');
        $this->db->join('team as t2', 't2.team_id = tf.team_team_id2');
        $this->db->join('fixture', 'tf.fixture_fixture_id = fixture.fixture_id');
        $this->db->join('venue', 'fixture_venue_id = venue.venue_id');
        $this->db->where('fixture_type', $fixture_type);
        $this->db->where('fixture_round', $fixture_round);
        $this->db->where('fixture_level', $fixture_level);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        //echo $this->db->last_query(); // Used this to see what my latest query contained

        if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
         $results = $query->result();
        }

        //var_dump($query->result()); // used this to see that the results of my query contained

        return $results;         
    }
```

It works perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you enable it in your config file: $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;

you can just use the get() method like so

```
$this->input->get('param_name');
```

So in your example maybe it would be

```
$fixture_round = $this->input->get('fixture_type');
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response - I tried what you asked but it had the effect of disabling the paths to images I am using elsewhere in my code. They use site Urls. As well as that I still got undefined variable errors.

Comment: Then why not use url segments for your parameters instead of url params if that is the case?  Or better yet...just create a form instead of anchors and send them via POST and skip the URL altogether?  If you absolutely need to use anchor tags instead, just use jquery or something to send the POST vars.